# Why is the runtime setting in AWS Lambda Layer optional?

Tags: aws-lambda

As per [AWS documentation on Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html), a Layer needs to have a compatible runtime defined in order to be used with a Lambda function. A quick test confirms that I cannot assign a Layer that has 0 runtimes selected.

Why is it so, and why is the Layer runtime setting optional? Arguably there are usecases where the Layer is runtime-agnostic (e.g. statically compiled executable, like imagemagick or ffmpeg). The limitation on 'compatible runtime' layer selection in Lambda function forces managing multiple standalone versions of (otherwise identical) Layers.